# Bar chart matplotlib based on array of 8 rows with 5 values each

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have an array off this form:

```
data = [[19, 14, 6, 36, 3],
        [12, 12, 1, 32, 1],
        [18, 25, 0, 33, 0],
        [13, 19, 0, 32, 5],
        [12, 14, 0, 33, 0],
        [16, 14, 7, 30, 0],
        [11, 18, 5, 31, 2],
        [17, 11, 3, 46, 7]]
```

I want to plot it as a bar chart. There would be 8 points on the x-axis, each having 5 bars, with heights corresponding to the 5 values in each row of the array. Would super appreciate any help!

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html

Answer (score 3):

There are two obtions using [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

### Single, adjacent bars

You can either plot the bars next to each other, in a grouped fashion, where you need to determine the bars' positions from the number of columns in the array.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[19, 14, 6, 36, 3],
                 [12, 12, 1, 32, 1],
                 [18, 25, 0, 33, 0],
                 [13, 19, 0, 32, 5],
                 [12, 14, 0, 33, 0],
                 [16, 14, 7, 30, 0],
                 [11, 18, 5, 31, 2],
                 [17, 11, 3, 46, 7]])
x = np.arange(data.shape[0])
dx = (np.arange(data.shape[1])-data.shape[1]/2.)/(data.shape[1]+2.)
d = 1./(data.shape[1]+2.)


fig, ax=plt.subplots()
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    ax.bar(x+dx[i],data[:,i], width=d, label="label {}".format(i))

plt.legend(framealpha=1).draggable()
plt.show()
```

### Stacked bars

Or you can stack the bars on top of each other, such that the bottom of the bar starts at the top of the previous one.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[19, 14, 6, 36, 3],
                 [12, 12, 1, 32, 1],
                 [18, 25, 0, 33, 0],
                 [13, 19, 0, 32, 5],
                 [12, 14, 0, 33, 0],
                 [16, 14, 7, 30, 0],
                 [11, 18, 5, 31, 2],
                 [17, 11, 3, 46, 7]])
x = np.arange(data.shape[0])

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    bottom=np.sum(data[:,0:i], axis=1)  
    ax.bar(x,data[:,i], bottom=bottom, label="label {}".format(i))

plt.legend(framealpha=1).draggable()
plt.show()
```